# Example of smooth compactly supported function

Tags: analysis, smooth-functions

Is there an easy example of a smooth compactly supported function (ie. a test function) that equals $e^x$ on the interval $[-1,1]$?

This is in reference to the following stack exchange question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130692/distribution-on-0-infty-which-cannot-be-extended-to-mathbbr?rq=1), where they describe a nice procedure but don't give an explicit example of such a function.

I've been trying to construct one and it does not seem obvious at all.
Is there something more explicit to know it's existence?

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but I suspect it will involve *mollifiers*.

Comment: The point is that you don't really *need* an explicit function---there are procedures for smoothly extending a function defined on a closed interval.  For example, you can "glue" a smooth transition function to the left side of $\mathrm{e}^x$ on $[-1,1]$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).  An explicit example is unlikely to be all that helpful---the *existence* of a function which does the job is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Consider
$$ 
f(x) = \begin{cases}\exp \left( \frac{-1}{x} \right)   \exp \left( \frac{-1}{x-1} \right) , &\qquad 0 < x < 1, 
\\
0, &\qquad x\notin (0,1).
\end{cases}  
$$
It's easy to check that $f$ is smooth and obviously supported in $(0,1)$.

**Step 2.** Take
$$
g(x)= f(x+1)-f(x-1). 
$$
Note that $\int g = 0$ and $g$ is supported in $(-1,2)$

**Step 3.** Consider
$$
G(x)=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x g(t)\,dt}{\int f}.
$$
Since $\int g=0$, G is supported in $(-1,2)$ and $G\equiv 1$ on $(0,1)$.

**Step 4.** A function satisfying your conditions is
$$
F(x)=e^x G(x/2+1/2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough knowledge to comment about your linked question, but a simple example of what you are asking for is considering the following continuous function:
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \quad x=0;\\ 0,\quad |x|\geq 10;\\
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(-\frac{20\left(|x|-5\right)}{x^2-10|x|}\right)},\,\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Then $g(x)$ is a class $C^\infty$ function that has *almost* a [flat top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) that equals to $g(x)=1$ between $x\in[-1,\ 1]$, and also it equals $g(x)=0$ for $|x|\geq 10$ (so, it is a smooth function with compact support - check [smooth bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)).

Now I can make the function:
$$f(x) = g(x)\ e^x$$
such $f(x)$ is another smooth function with compact support, but it *resembles* the exponential function in the interval $x\in[-1,\ 1]$ (*recall that $g(x)$ is not perfectly flat in the top side so $f(x)$ it is not a perfect match of the exponential function - but it is truly flat where it becomes zero*).

Check both in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xpsunsiuxv).

---

*Added later*

I'm not fully sure about this, but maybe this simpler version of $g(x)$ with support on $x\in[-2,\ 2]$ would help:
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \quad x=0;\\ 0,\quad |x|\geq 2;\\
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{28-16|x|}{x^2-2|x|}\right)},\,\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

which looks like this on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4tz7z2yyiu):
[image: last attempt]

*Caution here:  I am not sure if this last example is still class $C^\infty$.*